# Irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $x^2$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$? I claim it is. $0\cdot 0 = 0, 1 \cdot 1 = 1 \implies x^2 \equiv x$, so the factorization $x^2 = x\cdot x$ is not a factorization into proper divisors. Saying that $x^2$ is reducible would be the same thing as saying that $1$ is reducible because $1 = 1\cdot 1$.

Comment: This is a bit of a subtle mistake: you are confusing polynomials as formal objects with their associated functions. That is, $x^{2}$ and $x$ are equal as polynomial functions on $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, but not as elements of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: So it is not the case that $x^2 \equiv x$, merely $x^2 = x\ \forall x$?

Comment: The definition of irreducible is that $a=bc$ implies that either $b$ or $c$ is a unit in that ring, $x$ is not a unit in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$

Comment: Artin's text says: $a$ is irreducible if it is not a unit, and its only divisors are units and associates. The only divisors of $x^2$ are 1 and $x$: $1$ is a unit, and $x$ is an associate of $x^2$ because $x^2=x$.

Comment: The distinction between polynomial *functions* and polynomials is very important - you should make sure you're comfortable with it now. Later on it becomes crucial in defining the general finite fields - you just can't get proper field extensions of $\mathbb F_p$ if your polynomials are only thought of as functions.

Comment: @AlexWertheim I think it is best to write $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ or $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)[x]$ to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why is it that $3x \equiv x$, but $x^2 \not\equiv x$?